# How to access "nsf file" if Lotus notes not installed on your machine?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

Currently i can access nsf all nsg files.But once i uninstall Lotus Notes form my machine program doesn't work.

I am using "Introp.Domino.dll".
Language: C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this a long time ago, and if I remember it correctly it's not possible to use the Introp.Domino.dll without the Notes client installed.

A solution is to parse the xml returned when you add the " ?ReadViewEntries " to the nsf url.

```
youdominoserver/names.nsf?ReadViewEntries
```

Good luck,
rAyt

Comment: I second that thought.  I have always seen installing the Lotus Notes client as a requirement for any kind of interactivity with NSFs.  That goes for NotesSQL as well.

Comment: My solution works via a HTTP Request. Actually you can try it in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Lotus Notes installed then the only way to get access is to connect to a Domino server. There a couple of ways (if using C#).

**HTTP Examples.**

```
server/database.nsf/viewName?readviewentries
server/database.nsf/viewName?readviewentries&OutputFormat=JSON
server/database.nsf/viewName/docname?OpenDocument 
server/database.nsf/agentName?OpenAgent&variable=xxx
```

docName above would be the value of column 1 in the view for that item. You can also access using the UNID of each item. More examples on the [Domino wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/07282008102129AMKMKJU2.htm).

**Web Services**

Domino 7.x and later supports Web Service providers. 8.x supports Providers and consumers. Example.

```
server/database.nsf/webService?WSDL 
server/database.nsf/webService?OpenWebService
```